# How to mathematically express the inverted index?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I image the inverted index as the list of words which occurs in documents, e.g.:

```
w1 {d1, d2, d5, d7} // list of documents from a set D (D contains all the documents)
w2 {d3, d4}
w3 {d1, d5, d7, d8}
w4 {d1, d2, d5, d9}
w5 {d1}
..
wn {...}
```

Can you help me to express the "list of documents from a set D" mathematically?

Comment: I have no idea what this means (but I doubt it's anything to do with linear algebra, currently the only keyword).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the formulation of your question is a little scrimpy. But from what I understood you could define $W$ as the Set of "word indexes" (i.e. each word has an index $w \in W$), and $D$ as the set of "document indexes". Then write the mapping you describe as a Matrix $$I^{-1} \in \{0,1\}^{|W| \times |D|}$$
with $i_{w,k} = 1$ if the word with index $w \in W$ is contained in document with index $d \in D$.